# MySQL join results different in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, phpmyadmin

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM categorys 
LEFT JOIN category_info ON categorys.cat_id=category_info.cat_id 
WHERE `cat_name` = 'aname'
ORDER BY `cat_order`
```

When I run this in phpMyAdmin I get an cat_id back regardless of if there is a match in the second table.

However, when I run this query in my PHP code I get a blank cat_id back, as shown by this print_r():

> Array ( [cat_id] => [cat_name] => baths [type] => main [cat_order] =>
>   99 [cat_img] => [display] => 1 [deleted] => 0 [desc_id] => [desc] =>
>   [text] => )

Why would there be a different result when the query is exactly the same?

EDIT:
My PHP code:

```
$getcatidsql = "SELECT * FROM categorys 
LEFT JOIN category_info ON categorys.cat_id=category_info.cat_id 
WHERE `cat_name` = '{$cname}'
ORDER BY `cat_order";   
$getcatidresult = $db->query( $getcatidsql );
$catdata = $db->fetchRow( $getcatidresult );

function query() {
  $this->query_total++;
  if (func_num_args() == 1) {
    $sql = func_get_arg(0);
  } else {
    $args = func_get_args();
    for ($i=1;$i<count($args);$i++) if (!is_numeric($args[$i])) $args[$i] = '"'.mysql_real_escape_string($args[$i]).'"';
    $sql = vsprintf(array_shift($args),$args);
  }
  if ($result = mysql_query($sql,$this->db_connection)) {
    return $result;
  } else {
    $this->dberror( $this->db_connection, $sql );
  }
}

function fetchRow($result,$type=MYSQL_ASSOC)
{
    if($result)
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result,$type);
    return $row;
}
```

Comment: maybe you work with different databases?
show your php code

Comment: Nope same database. I was confused to why the query was going wrong in PHP so I used phpMyAdmin to debug it. That's when I saw the query was working just as I was expecting it to.

Comment: Did you use `LEFT JOIN` in both situations? LEFT JOIN is supposed to return every row from the left table (`categorys` in this case) at least once, even if there is no corresponding row in the right table.

Comment: so what about php code ? can you show it?

Comment: FYI, plural of `category` is `categories`, not `categorys`.

Comment: My only guess is that because the data doesn't exist the LEFT JOIN is putting NULL for all the rows in category_info (table 2) so maybe the NULL for category_info.cat_id is replacing what's in category.cat_id?

Comment: @cypher I know. I didn't write the database haha.

Comment: I don't want to state the obvious, but because the SQL strings aren't the same. They definitely won't hold up to stringcompare even with all whitespaces removed. You would have to extract the exact SQL passed to the function. Phpmyadmin may not use mysql_query at all but PDO instead.

Comment: so what now? if both tables are populated with data it works fine ?

Comment: You're missing a back-tick after cat_order.

Comment: @Fivell Yep. Only if the second table doesn't have a match.

Comment: Yes: you're SELECTing * from `categorys` and `category_info`. They both have a `cat_id` column. So you'll get two `cat_id` columns back. The question is: what does the SQL library/driver you're using do when it encounters two columns with the same name in your SELECT list? Looks like it's probably overwriting the first one it comes across with the second one... What happens if you use an explicit SELECT list, specifying `categorys.cat_id` and *not* bringing in `category_info.cat_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must not use select * (also because of same column names in both tables) ,  but select exactly fields for your needs

```
  select table_name.field, table_name.field2, other_table_name.field1
```

.. and you'll get right results from both php code and phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because 'cat_id' is the same field name in both tables => the same index in result array.
Try to modify query like : " Select categorys.cat_id AS category from categorys ..... "

Answer (score 1):

You're SELECTing * from `categorys` and `category_info`. They both have a `cat_id` column. So you'll get two `cat_id` columns back.

The question is: what does the SQL library/driver you're using do when it encounters two columns with the same name in your SELECT list?

Looks like it's probably overwriting the first one it comes across with the second one... What happens if you use an explicit SELECT list, specifying `categorys.cat_id` and *not* bringing in `category_info.cat_id`?

Comment: Thank you, this was right but someone answered first. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

When you state

> When I run this in phpMyAdmin I get an cat_id back

Do you mean that you get a VALUE for cat_id or do you get it as NULL? Because that is what you get with php, a NULL value for cat_id (as you see in print_r it still appears there).

If you don't want to get lines from `categorys` where there is no existing line in `category_info` for that category, then you have to use RIGHT JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN.

Comment: No I get a valid ID back in phpMyAdmin not NULL.